# Managing similar object classes

Tags: c#, object, architecture

In C# i am making a desktop application which has a list of objects from a class called Task. 
Each Task contains some Functions which will be executed by the Task when the Task is executed.

My question is how to manage the Functions since there are many types of Functions, there could be a Function with a class to move (In which case it would need vector data) there might also be a class to wait (in which case it would need some integer data).

What is the best way to go about doing this?

My idea is to have each type of function have its own class (wait class & move class) and all those classes inherit from a Function class which has the function Execute().
But even this doesn't work since I'll need to have the user change the data within each of those objects and since none will have the same type of data it gets very difficult.

This is a question about architecture because i am new to programming and i know i will make a bad call about how to go about it and will make my my program impossible to maintain, **the only issue with my current design is changing the child classes of function data, for instance knowing to ask for vector data instead of integer data.**

FYI There will be many of Function sub classes i only gave two examples, and each will have very unique data. (Links to resources are accepted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend from a base class/interface which has all the methods and use a property grid to populate each sub-class with it's unique class specific data.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can make from your post your talking about having Classes that extend a parent class. You would define a parent class (or interface) that would have the base methods for what you're doing. If you choose an interface you just make method stubs. The child class if extending a parent class can choose to override the method. If it is a class implementing an interface the class will be forced to make the methods defined in the interface.

Comment: Didn't even know what an interface was :( I'll read up on them now. Thanks